# Why do I get internet connection without a defined interface?

Tags: internet, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. I set the NAT networking option to it.
Without any further changes, I can access to internet from my VM. When I run: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` I get this:

```
ubuntu14@ubuntu14:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

How come I get internet connection without any interface defined for my NAT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are started automatically during the boot process. This is for for example `eth0` for the first ethernet

The entries for `lo (loopback)` are generally required and may also when using the `Network Manager` can not be removed or other graphical configuration tool.

Generally, `/etc/network/interfaces`  contains   network   interface   configuration
information  for the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands.  This is where you configure how your system is connected to the network.

Unless you manually configured `/etc/network/interfaces` with

`iface <Interface> <Protocoll> <Method>`

Your interface gets DHCP and connects you to the network.

These two entries:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

are fundamental components of Linux. If these entry's are gone, interfaces can no longer communicate with each other.

[Read More](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/interfaces.5.html) about network interface configuration.

Finally, I guess your VM gets a bridge interface from your host. You can list all your interfaces running `ifconfig -a` and you can see which interface connecting you to the internet.

Comment: You explained the important of the interface lo. However my question was about why there is no interface related to NAT networking option I set for my VM but even that I get internet access.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/network/interfaces` is only used for manually configured networking.

Your VM can access the internet because Ubuntu uses [network-manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) to configure the network. The configuration is stored in the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` Try `nmcli nm` or `nmcli d` to see the current network status.

Comment: There is nothing in my system-connections directory. I think you misunderstood my question: I do not have internet connection problem. I just wonder why I can connect while there is no defined interface (dhcp or static) in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @Massinissa I do not think I misunderstood. The answer to your question is that network-manager automatically configures network interfaces in Ubuntu. network-manager does not require `/etc/network/interfaces`. Try running `nmcli nm`

Comment: You are right that network-manager sets that, but where is the interface this network-manager set in order to be able to connect to internet ? I ask this because there is only the `lo` interface which is not responsible of being able to connect

Comment: Run `ifconfig -a` to see all of your network interfaces. You can see the one currently in use by running `route -n` (*Iface* column on right).

Comment: Now I see eth0 for the NAT with your commands ! That is the explanation ! But why can not I see eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces is an alternative (much older) configuration method. Network-manager does not use it. Network-manager directly queries the kernel to find network interfaces - you can do something similar by running `cat /proc/net/dev`

Comment: But what if I want to set a static IP address for my interface (suppose I want to add Host Only networking to my VM)

Comment: You can either set a static IP in /etc/network/interfaces and do `ifup eth0` to use it, or you can configure the static interface through network manager.